# Faster way to do this using Python, Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function in Python.  I would like to make it a lot faster?  Does anyone have any tips?

```
def garchModel(e2, omega=0.01, beta=0.1, gamma=0.8 ):

    sigma    = np.empty( len( e2 ) )
    sigma[0] = omega

    for i in np.arange(  1, len(e2) ):

        sigma[i] = omega + beta * sigma[ i-1 ] + gamma * e2[ i-1 ]

    return sigma
```

Comment: If you're gonna continue to use python, you should know it is not C, please read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for code formatting guidelines ;)

Comment: What is current performance result, for which lengths of e2 and what do you want to achive. I do not see alot of room for improvements

Comment: @alko, there's much room for improvement if the arrays are large, by avoiding the python-space loop.  A closed-form vectorized formula can be derived, using `beta**arange(N)`, `e2[:N-1]`...

Comment: Thanks for all the tips guys, but none of your suggestions seem to give the same answer as my original function.  ;{

Comment: Is your "original function" the code shown above?  I've compared Jaime's and my solution to yours, and they generate the same output (within normal floating point precision).  Jaime also shows that his function matches yours in his answer.  Could you provide a sample input `e2` and the expected output?

Comment: Warren, I will try to check this weekend!

Answer (score 5):

The following code works, but there's too much trickery going on, I am not sure it is not depending on some undocumented implementation detail that could eventually break down:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

def garch_model(e2, omega=0.01, beta=0.1, gamma=0.8):
    n = len(e2)
    sigma = np.empty((n,))
    sigma[:] = omega
    sigma[1:] += gamma * e2[:-1]
    sigma_view = as_strided(sigma, shape=(n-1, 2), strides=sigma.strides*2)
    inner1d(sigma_view, [beta, 1], out=sigma[1:])
    return sigma

In [75]: e2 = np.random.rand(1e6)

In [76]: np.allclose(garchModel(e2), garch_model(e2))
Out[76]: True

In [77]: %timeit garchModel(e2)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.93 s per loop

In [78]: %timeit garch_model(e2)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried using Numba, which for my dataset gives a 200x improvement!

Thanks for all the suggestions above, but I can't get them to give me the correct answer.  I will try to read up about linear filters, but it's Friday night now and I'm a bit too tired to take in anymore information.

```
from numba import autojit
@autojit
def garchModel2(e2, beta=0.1, gamma=0.8, omega=0.01, ):

    sigma    = np.empty( len( e2 ) )
    sigma[0] = omega

    for i in range(  1, len(e2) ):
        sigma[i] = omega + beta * sigma[ i-1 ] + gamma * e2[ i-1 ]

    return sigma
```

Comment: 200x is about what I get using @Jaime's answer, so if `numba` is a viable option for you, I think you are done. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution based on @stx2 's idea. One potential problem is that `beta**N` may cause float point overflow when `N` becomes large (same with `cumprod`).

```
>>> def garchModel2(e2, omega=0.01, beta=0.1, gamma=0.8):
    wt0=cumprod(array([beta,]*(len(e2)-1)))
    wt1=cumsum(hstack((0.,wt0)))+1
    wt2=hstack((wt0[::-1], 1.))*gamma
    wt3=hstack((1, wt0))[::-1]*beta
    pt1=hstack((0.,(array(e2)*wt2)[:-1]))
    pt2=wt1*omega
    return cumsum(pt1)/wt3+pt2

>>> garchModel([1,2,3,4,5])
array([ 0.01    ,  0.811   ,  1.6911  ,  2.57911 ,  3.467911])  
>>> garchModel2([1,2,3,4,5])
array([ 0.01    ,  0.811   ,  1.6911  ,  2.57911 ,  3.467911])
>>> f1=lambda: garchModel2(range(5)) 
>>> f=lambda: garchModel(range(5))
>>> T=timeit.Timer('f()', 'from __main__ import f')
>>> T1=timeit.Timer('f1()', 'from __main__ import f1')
>>> T.timeit(1000)
0.01588106868331031
>>> T1.timeit(1000) #When e2 dimension is samll, garchModel2 is slower
0.04536693909403766
>>> f1=lambda: garchModel2(range(10000))
>>> f=lambda: garchModel(range(10000))
>>> T.timeit(1000)
35.745981961394534
>>> T1.timeit(1000) #When e2 dimension is large, garchModel2 is faster
1.7330512676890066
>>> f1=lambda: garchModel2(range(1000000))
>>> f=lambda: garchModel(range(1000000))
>>> T.timeit(50)
167.33835501439427
>>> T1.timeit(50) #The difference is even bigger.
8.587259274572716
```

I didn't use `beta**N` but `cumprod` instead. `**` will probably slow it down a lot.

Comment: It doesn't work, the overflow happens very soon, at around 10000 items already. Try `np.allclose(garchModel(range(10000)), garchModel2(range(10000)))` and you will get a big `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is a linear filter of the sequence `omega + gamma*e2`, so you can use [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).  Here's a version of your calculation, with appropriate tweaks of the initial conditions and input of the filter to generate the same output as `garchModel`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter

def garch_lfilter(e2, omega=0.01, beta=0.1, gamma=0.8):
    # Linear filter coefficients:
    b = [1]
    a = [1, -beta]

    # Initial condition for the filter:
    zi = np.array([beta*omega])

    # Preallocate the output array, and set the first value to omega:
    sigma = np.empty(len(e2))
    sigma[0] = omega

    # Apply the filter to omega + gamma*e2[:-1]
    sigma[1:], zo = lfilter(b, a, omega + gamma*e2[:-1], zi=zi)

    return sigma
```

Verify that it gives the same result as @Jaime's function:

```
In [6]: e2 = np.random.rand(1e6)

In [7]: np.allclose(garch_model(e2), garch_lfilter(e2))
Out[7]: True
```

It is a lot faster than `garchModel`, but not as fast as @Jaime's function.

Timing for @Jaime's `garch_model`:

```
In [8]: %timeit garch_model(e2)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 ms per loop
```

Timing for `garch_lfilter`:

```
In [9]: %timeit garch_lfilter(e2)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.8 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jaime shows, there's a way. However, I don't know if there's a way to rewrite the function, make it much faster, *and* keep it simple.

An alternative approach then, is using optimization "magics", such as [cython or numba](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/15/numba-vs-cython-take-2/).