# Efficient way to compute GARCH recursion

Tags: python, numpy

Given parameters `alpha`, `beta`, and `omega`, and an array `u` the following recursion must be computed to fill an array `sigma2`:

```
sigma2[t] = omega ** 2 + alpha * u[t-1] ** 2 + beta * sigma2[t-1]
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this (ie. avoid a `for` loop)? I tried to look for a `numpy` version of `fold` but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to ask about `sigma2[t]` and not `sigma2[i]`? `i` isn't used as an argument in the rest of the expression. Also, where does it terminate? I'm assuming `u` starts at index `0` and the recursion is expected to terminate at `sigma2[0]`? If so, what is the value for `sigma2[0]`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Let’s assume there is an initial value and goes on as long as it can.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576049/faster-way-to-do-this-using-python-numpy